# Git flow: How to configure a one-click release process in Jenkins?

Tags: java, git, jenkins, git-flow, jgitflow-maven-plugin

We are using the standard git flow branching model (develop, master, release-*, hotfix-*, etc).

As part of our workflow, we would like to set up a "one-click" release via jenkins.

I was looking at the [jgitflow-maven-plugin](https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/jgit-flow/wiki/Home). Can I set up this plugin to do a one-click release from jenkins? If so, what are the configuration options?

In particular, can I do something like this?

```
Jenkins Job
Maven goals:    release-start release-finish -Dsomething -Delse
```

And is there a way tell it to automatically build from the latest -SNAPSHOT version, e.g. if the version is `1.2.3-SNAPSHOT` it would build `release-1.2.3`.

Otherwise, is there a maven plugin that builds releases *according the git flow branching model* (i.e. build from `develop` and create a new release branch named `release-x.y.z`).

Comment: Did you manage it in the meantime? if yes, how?

Comment: No, we didn't get it working yet. Still doing mvn release:prepare and release:perform (which, as we all know, is a royal pain in the b**t).

Comment: Just a little update here, we are working with a unix script named `release.sh` which does the following: `git flow release start ...`, `mvn -B release:prepare`, `mvn release:perform`, `git flow release finish ...`. It's not ideal, and it doesnt work from windows machines, but it's the best solution we have right now.

Comment: Hi I'm working on the similar stuff at the moment, I tried 'gitflow-maven-plugin' , basic you can update the version with a single command (still not completely automate though) and I'm still figuring how to combine this with Jenkins, just wondering if you managed to get it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We never found a way to get this to work via a plugin or maven goal in Jenkins.

Our solution ended up with a `bash` script that did `git flow release start <version>`, maven release process, `git flow release finish <version>` and other things (git pull on `develop` and `master` at very start, git `push` and slack notification at very end).

Answer (score 14):

Although this answer is one year old I'd like point out that meanwhile the jgitflow (`v1.0-m5.1`) works with maven batch mode.

So to release an artifact with just **one command** you can execute:

```
mvn --batch-mode jgitflow:release-start jgitflow:release-finish
```

You **don't** need to set `developmentVersion` and `releaseVersion`.

JGitFlow will use the current version minus the `-SNAPSHOT` part as release version. Then it increments the least significant digit and adds `-SNAPSHOT` again for the next development version.
**Example** `1.0.0-SNAPSHOT` --> Release: `1.0.0`, next Development version: `1.0.1-SNAPSHOT`

In order to configure a **single click Jenkins release job** you need to configure some things regarding Git.

Under `Source Code Management > Git > Additional Behaviors` select

- `Wipe out repository & force git clone`: just to make sure the workspace is clean
- `Checkout to specific local branch`: your `develop` branch.

Finally, the release happens locally on your Jenkins server, so you want to **push back the changes** to your Git remote server.

To accomplish this, the easiest way is to add a `Post-build action` which executes the following bash command (the branch names may vary, I've used the JGitFlow default values):

```
git push origin develop master --tags
```

**Note** If Jenkins is running on Windows you either have to execute a Batch script containing the same command (sometimes this doesn't work due to SSH issues with Windows) or configure the `Git Publisher` `Post-build action` accordingly.

Comment: Looks promising, Ill test this out. Thank you.

Comment: Basically, it comes down to these four commands packaged as Jenkins job: `git clone <repo url> . && git checkout develop &&
mvn --batch-mode jgitflow:release-start jgitflow:release-finish &&
git push origin develop master --tags
`

Comment: @gucce your steps worked great. Given that jgitflow hasn't seen active development in a while, have you had success with any other git flow maven plugins?

Comment: @testphreak No, I'm not aware of any other maven plugins. Although it is not under active development (and maybe never will be again, see [1]), we have not encountered any problems preventing us from using it for our current project. For the next project I don't know if we'll use it again. [1] https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/maven-jgitflow-users/NeVNHqD7a8w

Comment: Just wanted to point out you don't need to add the push command, there is a paramter for that: -DpushReleases=true. We use this and it makes the jenkins job dead simple. https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/jgit-flow/wiki/goals/release-start#!pushreleases

Comment: I used 'gitflow-maven-plugin' to update the versioning instead of 'jgitflow-maven-plugin', just wonderin what's the difference between them? I assume we can only configure and work with Jenkins via 'jgitflow-maven-plugin' instead of ''gitflow-maven-plugin'?

Comment: 'Under Source Code Management > Git' Is it in Jenkins platform? Or IntelliJ?

Comment: @Cecilia Jenkins, of course. No one said anything about IntelliJ on this page.

Comment: I didn't find this configuration in my Jenkins, is it possible that I don't have the valid privilege to do so? @gucce

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the jenkins plugin [M2 Release Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/M2+Release+Plugin) with the release goals an options 
`-B  -DautoVersionSubmodules=true jgitflow:release-start jgitflow:release-finish`

Comment: Ok. Are you sure jgitflow can work in batch mode? Last i tried it, it required a `version` parameter of some sort.

Comment: @vikingsteve Use **developmentVersion** and **releaseVersion properties**, see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

We ended up with starting the release via CLI on the client (because in Jenkins there is a [bug](https://ecosystem.atlassian.net/browse/MJF-273) starting the release).

```
git flow release start -DautoVersionSubmodules=true
```

If you want to use the batch mode you need to specify **developmentVersion** and **releaseVersion**.

Created a new job in Jenkins to build the release branch and use the [M2 Release Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/M2+Release+Plugin) to release it finally:

```
-B jgitflow:release-finish
```

If you use some custom profiles, you have to pass them additional via **arguments** caused by a [bug](https://ecosystem.atlassian.net/browse/MJF-278).

```
-Darguments=-Pprofile
```