# Jenkins pipeline - undo a jgitflow release on fail

Tags: git, jenkins, github, jenkins-pipeline, jgitflow-maven-plugin

I am following [Git flow: How to configure a one-click release process in Jenkins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29532101/git-flow-how-to-configure-a-one-click-release-process-in-jenkins?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) to implement release process with Jenkins pipeline. However I am not sure what should I do to reset develop branch if something will fail.

This is a part on my pipeline stage:

```
try {
    sh "mvn -f jgitflow:release-start -B -U -DskipTests"

    try {
        sh "mvn -f jgitflow:release-finish -B -U -DskipTests -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true -DnoDeploy=false"
    } catch(err) {
        currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'
        println("Cannot finish a release, undoing...")

        //undoing

        return
    }

} catch(err) {
    currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'
    println("Release failed")
    return
}
```

Should I discover a `release` branch (with `regexp`) and delete it, then do a `git reset --hard HEAD~1` to reset a `develop` branch?

Are there any other ways to do it?

Comment: the main objective in the question doesn't seem to have any co-relation with git flow. Its more about how to use Git. If your code is not compiling error free, you fix the code and re-build it. Why do you think, you have to  do a reset --hard HEAD~1?  This will delete your history and even more dangerous when you have committed to the remote

Comment: I just want to restore the previous state of repository if something fails, e.g. I don't want to keep a commit increasing a snapshot version of pom on develop branch and I don't want to keep a release branch anymore.

Comment: For the release branch or any branch, if you dont need it. just delete it. To delete it locally:  `git branch -d feature/login` and to delete it from the remote: `git push origin --delete feature/login`. And for the other question: not a recommended standard process, to try and delete if failed from a remote repo. Try and build the project locally first, before you push

Comment: So should I disable automatic pushing with jgitflow, then perform release-start operation, finally, if everything will be ok, push local changes to remote? 
The same flow for release-finish?
I am not a git expert, I am sorry.

Comment: i am sorry, i can't really advise without having an understanding on your local env. But all the code/jenkins pipeline, that you shared in the OP will be executed for codes that reaches the git repo. What i do and many others is to build the code locally in my workstation even before i push, like `mvn install`. And if this looks okay locallu, do a `git push` to remote to be shared with the collaborators.

Comment: I think that you have helped me to understand a real problem, thank you.